What probability distribution function is this?
This is sort of a followup to this question (I'll mention everything relevant in this post though so no need to click link).

Main Question:
I was trying to study a random variable $Y$. I will describe it here: Suppose we flip a fair coin $L$ times. Then, we let the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_s$ represent the counts of consecutive runs. For example, if $L = 5$, and I flip $$HHTHH,$$ then $X_1 = 2$ (two heads), $X_2 = 1$ (followed by one tails), $X_3 = 2$ (followed by two heads). In this example, we let $s$ be the count of the number of consecutive runs (3 in this example). Now, I want to understand the behavior of $Y = \prod (X_i+1)$ as $L \to \infty$. Specifically, I want to understand how the pdf/cdf of the limiting probability distribution looks like. Originally, I thought this would be a messy probability distribution with nothing interesting about it. However, when I graphed the pmf (histogram with about 200 bins for the log of the value of the RV) for $L = 17$ or $18$, I got something cool (shown below). Can someone provide some insight into what $Y$, or $Pr(Y < a)$ is? Thanks! 
Please explain this like I’m an undergrad who kinda paid attention in probability class for the first half of the semester.

One suggestion for a possible answer (though I am slightly skeptical):
$$Pr(Y < a) \approx Pr\left(\log \prod_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{L}{2}\right\rfloor} 1 + Geo(1/2) < \log(a)\right)$$
One thing that was suggested was to model each $X_i$ as a geometric random variable $G_i$. Then, if we let $Z_s = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{s}(G_i + 1)$, then we take $\log(Z_s)$, we can use the central limit theorem and send $s \to \infty$. It was then suggested that since $s$ will be about $L/2$, we can approximate the distribution (pdf/cdf) of $Y$ with $Z_{\lfloor L/2 \rfloor}$. While this explains the lognormal shape, I would now like to know why it is this is the case. Specifically, why can we approximate the $X_i$'s with i.i.d. geometric random variables as $L \to \infty$ (necessary for CLT) and why the "distribution of $Y$ converges to the distribution of $Z_{\lfloor L/2 \rfloor}$." Specifically, it was suggested that $\mathbb{P}(Y< a)=\mathbb{P}(\log Z_{L/2}< \log  a)
=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\log Z_{L/2}-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}< \frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)\asymp \Phi\left(\frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)$
This does explain the lognormal shape as expected.
If this is the wrong way to approach this problem, please explain why and what I should do instead.
And if it is correct, can someone work out the details of this (law of large numbers + CLT analysis details) and as a followup, when is it in general where we can make these approximations?

Graph of pmf (looks like lognormal?)
Below, I graphed a rough histogram of the distribution of the value of the random variable when $L$ is around 17. Some of the details might be off but theres is some lognormal shape to it and I wish to understand where this shape comes from and whether the random variable $Y$ tends to something nice like that below.
THIS GRAPH IS WRONG, NEW GRAPH COMING SOON (BUT STILL LOGNORMAL)


You need to be more precise than "the distribution of $Y$ converges to the distribution of ($Z_{\lfloor L/2\rfloor}$, or anything else) as $L \to \infty$" because the distribution of $Y$ diverges as $L \to \infty$. (It doesn't have a limiting CDF, because for any $a$, $\lim_{L \to \infty} \Pr[Y \le a] = 0$.) As in the central limit theorem, you need to normalize $Y$ somehow before you can talk about its limiting distribution.

I'm not exactly sure how to formulate this, but I do know that from graphing the distribution of this random variable, it takes a loglognormal shape and I was wondering why that is.

Btw I am referring to the answer in the linked post, where someone suggested, $\mathbb{P}(Y< a)=\mathbb{P}(\log Z_{L/2}< \log  a)
=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\log Z_{L/2}-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}< \frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)\asymp \Phi\left(\frac{\log a-L\mu/2}{\sigma\sqrt{L/2}}\right)$, maybe convergence isn't the right term for this. Though the shape is correct, I am slightly skeptical of this answer.

Well, note that the $X_i$s aren't really very dependent. In fact $P(X_i = x| X_1^{i-1}) \approx P(X_i = x)$. The reason is simply that once a new run begins, you draw fresh coins, so the length of this run has nothing to do with what happened previously - the only issue is that the total length of $X_i$ can't exceed $L - \sum_{j < i} X_j$ - but, at least if $i < 0.49 L$ for $L \gg 1,$ this length limit is typically of order $0.02 L \gg 1,$ but the usual size of the $X_i$s wihtout this limit would be about $2$. It follows that modelling the $X_i$s as roughly $L/2$ iid geometrics would retain

(contd.) a lot of fidelity. In general, the subject is one of studying "weak dependence" between random variables. This should be treated in graduate probability textbooks.

ty ty,  can u point me to some references? i am a noob in probability. the part that i'm skeptical about is that the value of the rv kinda "explodes" as L gets large especially near the end where the X_i gets abruptly cut off by the total length L.

@stochasticboy321 is it true then that $Pr(Y < a) \to Pr(\log Z_{L/2} < \log a)$ and if not, how could i understand the error, $| Pr(Y < a)  - Pr(\log Z_{L/2} < \log a) |$

The graph should look like lognormal, and is in fact approximately lognormal, because the lognormal distribution is the result of "multiplicative version of CLT". If you multiply IID positive random variables (with its logarithm having finite second moment), the resulting variable will be approximately lognormal.

i have established the fact that it would be lognormal IF i can model this with iid geo, but the question is whether this is actually the case because there is a binding condition that the sum of the X_i's must be L

@SangchulLee If the "multiplicative version of CLT" suggests that $\log Y$ is asymptotically normal, then the histogram of $\log Y$ should tend to "look normal" -- but instead the above histogram of $\log Y$ perhaps "looks lognormal" (or at least not normal), suggesting that $\log\log Y$ may be asymptotically normal (i.e., that $Y$ may be "log log normal").

@r.e.s. If I read correctly, the histogram is about $Y$ and not $\log Y$. Or am I misreading OP?

@SangchulLee He says "Below, I graphed a rough histogram of the distribution of the log of the value of the random variable".

@r.e.s., Oh, I see that now, sorry. Let me see if I can replicate OP's histogram, and if it is indeed the histogram of $\log Y$, I will think about this. What I realized is that OP is fixing the total number $L$ of coin tosses and not the total number of "turnovers" (which I originally thought after careless reading). So, my original claim may be indeed wrong.

I tried to replicate the histogram, but my simulation does not match what OP has shown. I used both Mathematica 14 and python to generate $10^8$ samples, $Y_1$, $\ldots$, $Y_{10^8}$, from $Y$ with $L=17$ and then tried plotting the histogram for both $Y_i$'s and $\log_{10}Y_i$'s. None of them matched OP's histogram.

@SangchulLee oops, you are correct. It should be lognormal, I accidently plotted a loglognormal distribution shown above. i'll try to fix it rn

I just want to point out that (a) the log normal distribution has notoriously slow convergence in the tails. ( b) instead of fixing $L$, ala the microcanonical ensemble, the canonical ensemble of fixing $s$ is much easier and cleaner to simulate, and asymptotically should give the same distribution

For $Y_L$ defined as the simple product of the run-lengths in a sequence of $L$ i.i.d. coin tosses, here is what I find in simulated samples of size $10^7$: The empirical CDF of $\log Y_L$ is hardly distinguishable from that of a normal distribution with the same mean and variance when $L\ge 50$.

This is just my (not very rigorous) summary of the arguments in the comments (community wiki).
Let $R$ be the number of runs ($R=3$ in your example).
In the original setting we have $L$ as a fixed parameter, and $R$ is a random variable. Indeed, $R$ follows a $Bin(L-1,\frac12)$  (binomial) distribution, hence $E(R)= \frac12 (L +1)$ and $\sigma_R^2 = \frac14 (L-1)$.
Also, letting ${\bf X}=(X_1,X_2 \cdots X_r)$,  $$P({\bf X}) = \sum_r P({\bf X}|  R=r) P(R=r) \tag 1$$
and
$$P(g({\bf X})) = \sum_r P(g({\bf X})|  R=r) P(R=r) \tag 2$$
For large $L$, $P(R=r)$ concentrates around its mean, hence (assuming $g(X)$ is smooth) we can approximate $(2)$ by
$$P(g({\bf X})) \approx  P(g({\bf X})|  R= L/2) \tag 3$$
Now, when we condition on $R=r$, the joint prob of $X_i$ is uniform over all the configurations s.t the sum is fixed : $\sum_{i=1}^r X_i = L$. If we instead consider $r$ iid geometric variables $Z_i$ with paramenter $p=\frac12$ and support on $1,2 \cdots...$, the joint probability is $P(Z)=\prod 2^{-Z_i}=2^{-\sum Z_i}$
which is indeed uniform over the regions of constant sum. Because $E[Z_i]=2$, by picking $r=L/2$, the sum will, again, concentrate around the mean $L$ and we can further approximate $(3)$
$$ P(g({\bf X})) \approx P(g({\bf Z}))$$
Now, $$Y = \prod (X_i+1) = \exp \sum \log (X_i +1)$$
Under the above approximation, the variables $W_i=\log (X_i +1)$ can be approximated by $\log (Z_i +1)$ where $Z_i$ are iid (and hence also $W_i$). Further, $\mu_W \approx 1.01566678$ and $\sigma^2_W \approx 0.147$
For large $L$ (say, above $L>50$) we can apply the CLT, so the $\sum W_i$ tends to a gaussian with $\mu = 1.01566678 L/2$ and $\sigma^2 =  0.147 L /2$, and $Y$ tends to a log normal distribution.
